# apache mod_proxy and original URL

Tags: mod-proxy, proxypass, apache-2.2

I have apache 2.2 mod_proxy working well for the most part, but are having some trouble with some of our newer tools.

We have the config file for one server below.

Our problem is, when a user goes to web.example.com/app1/prd/test.php
the end application only sees a few things.. the current URL request it sees is webprd.example.local:8194/test.php
and the header:
X-Forwarded-Host:web.example.com

How can I write a header into the request, that would include the full URL/URI that the original requester had?  The application needs that info for our usage. Something like 
X-Forwarded-URI:web.example.com/app1/prd/test.php
Or we could even skip the host, since that is another header.

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443>
        #removed some ssl and log related settings.
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyBadHeader Ignore
        ServerName web.example.com


        #app1
        ProxyPass /app1/dev/ https://webdev.example.local:4433/ timeout=600
        ProxyPassReverse /app1/dev/ https://webdev.example.local:4433/
        ProxyPass /app1/test/ http://webtest.example.local:8194/ timeout=600
        ProxyPassReverse /app1/test/ http://webtest.example.local:8194/
        ProxyPass /app1/prd/ http://webprd.example.local:8194/ timeout=600
        ProxyPassReverse /app1/prd/ http://webprd.example.local:8194/
        ProxyPass /app1/ http://webprd.example.local:8194/ timeout=600
        ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://webprd.example.local:8194/
        #app2
        ProxyPass /app2/dev/ http://webdev.example.local:16222/ 
        ProxyPassReverse /app2/dev/ http://webdev.example.local:16222/
        ProxyPass /app2/test/ http://webtest.example.local:16222/ 
        ProxyPassReverse /app2/test/ http://webtest.example.local:16222/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about setting a header, as that seems a little convoluted. But you could simply include the same URI in the Proxy, as in:

```
ProxyPass /app1/prd/ http://webprd.example.local:8194/app1/prd/ timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse /app1/prd/ http://webprd.example.local:8194/app1/prd/
```

I'm not sure why you need this information so I can't be sure, but wouldn't this solve your issue?